# Why defaultValue does not work in <TextInput />?

Tags: ios, react-native, default-value, textinput

Here is what I am trying to do ,
here is message box component which has TextInput using defaultValue
Works well in android but nothing for iOS

```
<MessageBox
  defaultValue={this.state.defaultData}
  value={this.state.new_content}
/>
     
<TextInput
  defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
  value={props.value}
/>
```